# Grafana Prometheus pie chart time range

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm using Grafana to chart Prometheus data.  I have a set of data in gauges and it's displaying just fine on line charts.  When I try and use a pie chart it only seems to show the most recent data point, not the sum for the whole time range selected in the dashboard.

I'm trying this:

`sum(successful_requests)`

Is there something I need to do to get it to sum all the data in the time range?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: The question I have is why are you using a gauge and not a counter for total requests. Is this the result of a recorded rule? Otherwise you're walking on very shaky ground.

Answer (score 5):

Ok - I just figured it out thanks to an article about sum_over_time.  You can do it like this:

`sum(sum_over_time(total_requests[$__interval]))`

The outer sum is good if you are trying to aggregate multiple series together, otherwise you can do without:

`sum_over_time(total_requests[$__interval])`

Ian

Comment: Can you please link to the article would be useful for others to have it as a reference.